# iOS reminders app not syncing with Yosemite

Tags: reminders

I was working in the reminders app last night and noticed that it failed to sync across all my devices, which run the latest version of OS X and iOS. I've tried to sign out of iCloud on my iOS devices but it keeps asking whether I want to delete the content from my iPhone and wasn't sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning reminders in icloud off and back on. It might prompt for keeping the existing reminders locally when it is turned off in which case you can select `yes`. When you turn it back on, it might ask for merging reminders and select `yes` again. This has worked for me in the past.