# Reminders won't sync to iPhone

Tags: ios, icloud, reminders

Running iOS 8.1 on an iPad mini, Yosemite on an Air, and 8.1 on a 5C.

For whatever reason, the 5C has stopped syncing reminders to/from iCloud. Works fine between the iPad and Air.

So far I've tried disabling reminder sync on the iPhone (not entire iCloud), and rebooted. When I open Reminders now everything is gone (expected) but none of the lists sync down. Reminders is stuck in a state where the only visible button is the "New List +" section, which does not react to taps.

If I turn off sync and open the app, I'm presented with "New List +" and a default empty "Reminders" sheet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Potentially related: [iOS reminders app not syncing with Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155555/ios-reminders-app-not-syncing-with-yosemite)

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What worked for me:

- Disable reminders in iCloud settings
- Open reminders
- On the default reminders list create a random task, e.g. "Test"
- Re-enable reminders in iCloud settings
- "Merge" reminders
- Open reminders and wait for the sync to finish

Comment: I think the third step where you create a random task is the crucial one. Somehow if you have no reminders on the iPhone, it doesn't want to sync. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Nearly seven years later, and this worked for me on my iPad. But I had to do one more step: Quit reminders (by swiping up in the app switcher screen) and then restart the app. On second thought, maybe I should have tried that first. It just might have done the job. But +1 from me anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, until I realized that the in the iPhone's iCloud settings, Reminders is unchecked by default. So all I did - on my iPhone - was go to Settings > iCloud and then just activate Reminders. Within a few seconds all my Reminders between my iPhone and Mac were synced.

Answer (score 1):

on the date October 1, 2019 the problem is with Apple

> iOS 13 came out a couple of weeks ago, but one thing you may have noticed is that Reminders no longer sync with Macs. Apple has now confirmed that Reminders won't update until its latest macOS update is made available.
>
> The new version of Reminders for iPhone impressed us with its improvements in iOS 13.1. However, to sync Reminders between an iPhone and a Mac requires macOS 10.15, a.k.a. Catalina, which is released in the coming weeks.

Comment: That's bad news if you can't or don't want to upgrade your Mac.

Comment: Right now I can't update, because release is still not released :)

Comment: Can you add a link to the source of this information?

Comment: @nekomatic, seems to be this: https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/apple-confirms-ios-13-reminders-will-be-fixed-with-macos-catalina-rollout/ar-AAI7203?srcref=rss

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to fully sign out of icloud on the phone and deleting all icloud data off phone then signing in again to icloud. Reminders then sync'ed.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to Calendars and Reminders on iCloud which must be followed. Reminders or lists which surpass those limits will not be synced, and will be reverted back to the previous state. Reminders below the limits will sync fine.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202158

In my case, my list title had over 100 characters in length, and some of my reminders had over 1000 characters in length. The list always reverted to "New list" (default name) after renaming, and the reminders were not synced at all, and would disappear from the device after a while.

So if some of your reminders or calendars aren't syncing, check if they are over the iCloud limits. As far as iCloud is concerned, "Lists" (inside Reminders app) and Calendars are the same thing (EKCalendar), so their limits are also the same.

*I know this is not the solution for jlindenbaum's specific problem, but I came to this question with iCloud sync problems and was wondering why it wasn't working even after having followed a lot of advice and different answers to this question. So my answer is to help people with the same problem I had with iCloud sync.*

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out be the number of completed reminders - the limits. I deleted all my completed reminders, and it syncs properly now.