# Handoff of completed Reminder items not working?

Tags: macos, icloud, reminders

I have a MBP running MacOS Sierra (10.12.1) and an iPhone 6 running iOS v10.1.1. Over the past few months or so, I've noticed that marking a Reminder as complete on either of those devices does not clear the notification on the other, nor does it mark the reminder as complete on the other. I'm not sure why.

Both devices are with me and using the same wifi (the vast majority of the time). Handoff is enabled on my iPhone. The Reminders app on both devices syncs to iCloud.

I can answer calls and texts on my Mac and when I open Safari on iOS, I can access the open tab on my Mac as expected. This makes me think that, generally speaking, Handoff is working as expected, but not for Reminders.

Is there something else I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To clarify - Syncing reminders between apple devices is not part of handoff. It is based on iCloud sync only. Handoff is something that happens when your devices are on same WIFI and also use same apple id as primary iCloud account (Concept of primary iCloud account applies to macOS only as it supports multiple iCloud accounts). Calls and messages use Handoff.*

**Solution 1**

Now to your problem, you might have multiple apple ids (accounts) on your devices and reminders might be using different apple ids in different devices.

**To verify on your macOS** -

1. Goto System Preferences -> Internet Accounts
2. Check the iCloud accounts and make sure the correct iCloud account has reminders enabled.
3. If you are using more than one iCloud accounts, then open Reminders app on macOS and check on lists on the left menu for the
   iCloud account being used. It would of the format `iCloud (<account name>)`. You could also migrate the reminders to correct iCloud
   account by drag/drop and then uncheck the unwanted iCloud account
   for reminders in settings as stated in (1) & (2) above.

**To verify on your iPhone -**

1. Goto settings -> iCloud
2. Make sure reminders is turned on and the account is correct and same as on macOS

**Solution 2**

Toggle reminders in iCloud settings on your devices one by one and see if the sync starts again. The steps to access the settings is same as above.

Hope this helps.

*Update: Added second solution of toggling reminders*

Comment: Thanks. I have 1 iCloud account and Reminders are enabled. Within Reminders, all of my lists are in the "iCloud" group. I verified the iOS settings as well.

Comment: Some times it helps if you turn off reminders for iCloud and then turn it back on. Make sure you back it up or i think it does prompt if you want to keep existing reminders locally when you turn it off in iCloud. Check this. It suggests similar - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157943/213255

Comment: On my Mac, toggling Reminders under the iCloud setting seems to have worked! Thanks.